# GNU Make: How to figure the dependencies for a code generator that can generate several modules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, code-generation

I have a code generator, that can generate code for several modules in one run. The modules to generate, and all input files have to be provided on the command line.
The complicated part is that all modules have different set of input files. The list of files can also overlap.
I want to create a rule that checks the prerequisites for all modules, and invokes the generator with only the modules that need to be re-generated, and preferably the list of required files without duplicates.

Example:
module_A depends on infile, infile_A1 and infile_A2
module_B depends on infile, infile_A1 and infile_B

The generator has to be invoked this way:

```
generator -m module1 -m module2 file1 file2 ...
```

The goal would be constructing a command line with the proper -m options for all modules that need to be re-generated, and with all the input files that are required by all the modules.

I started creating something like this, not yet finished:
(MODULE_INPUT_FILES is already defined somewhere else for all modules)

```
# Check the prerequisites for one module, and touch the label if the module needs to be re-generated
define PROC_MODULE
$(GEN_OUTPUT_PATH)/$1_GEN: $($1_INPUT_FILES)
    $(CMD_TOUCH) $(GEN_OUTPUT_PATH)/$1_GEN
endef

# Create a file with the list of modules that need to be generated. $? collects all prerequisites that were touched above.
define GEN_MODULES
$(foreach m,$1,$(eval $(call PROC_MODULE,$m)))
$(GEN_OUTPUT_PATH)/ALL_GEN_READY: $(foreach m,$1,$(GEN_OUTPUT_PATH)/$m_GEN)
    @$(CMD_ECHO) $$? >$(GEN_OUTPUT_PATH)/MODULES_TO_GENERATE
    @$(CMD_TOUCH) $(GEN_OUTPUT_PATH)/ALL_GEN_READY
endef

# Create rules that generates the given modules as needed
$(call GEN_MODULES,module_A module_B module_C)
$(call GEN_MODULES,module_D)
```

So far so good... It seems to be working. Now I could go ahead, produce the list of module names from that file with sed, produce the generator command line and so.
But isn't there a better solution?
E.g. is there a function that accepts a target and its prerequisites, and returns whether the recipe needs to run or not?

Comment: The short answer to your last question is no, there is no such function.  Basically that's the entirety of what make does, and there's no function that encompasses the entirety of what make does.

Comment: It would be much more natural to write rules expressing the dependencies of each module, with a recipe for each that runs the generator to create / update just that module.  Is it really so bad to run the generator separately for each?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes because the generator is Java based, and needs to load the entire AUTOSAR model. It's very slow, but that's another option. The idea here is to improve the performance. Anyway you're right, the old solution is easier to implement.

Comment: Well then, if loading the generator and data is so expensive, then perhaps it makes sense to just regenerate all the modules unconditionally at need?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sure that works too. Slower than the "perfect" solution but might be acceptable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Meanwhile managed to make it working! No sed needed, make has enough text processing functionality to deal with it. The labels for the individual modules are now placed into a subfolder and the name does not have the _GEN suffix, it's easier this way.
Processing the makefiles is a bit slower due to having to resolve all individual module dependencies and then figure which modules need to be reloaded, but generation is as fast as possible.